# Moving a MySQL database to Parse.com and using it from php

Tags: php, mysql, parse-platform, relational

First of all, i have a content management system written in PHP & MySQL. (+ HTML, jQuery etc.) And i'm currently using it to manage data in my ios app (Local News and Weather) by using JSON generated by CMS.

After some research, i decided moving CMS database to Parse, because it can manage backend for me. But i'm disappointed because of Parse's object database model.

So, here is my question, is there any way to store and query data like MySQL & PHP in Parse?

Sorry for bad english.

Thanks.

Comment: then why did you move to parse in the first place? "Gee, I really like the color of the walls in this cardboard box, but the box really should be a ferrari... how do I install a steering wheel and motor?"

Comment: Thanks for answering, you're right, but i want to train myself for future projects. Please do not think this question is project specific.

Comment: If you simply want to train yourself, maybe you should get adapted to Parse's model. Otherwise, you may roll back to your previous database structure.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Okay, i will adapt myself to Parse model. I'm just wondering, say i have a comment section for News, currently i am using news_id on Comments table to keep track of News comments. How can i achieve this with Parse? I am thinking of querying Comments table for news_id than print the results. Is this a Parse way to do querying?